# Compute percentage of rows in group that have a certain value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the dataset [birthwt](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-51.4/topics/birthwt).

For each age, I want to find the percentage of mothers that are white. My end goal is to display that percentage in a plot by age. How can I do this? I'm learning how to use tidyverse functions so I would prefer to do it that way if possible. Here is my work so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyselect)
library("MASS")

grouped <- birthwt %>%
  count(race, age)  %>%
  spread(key = race, value = n, fill = 0)

grouped
```

This gets a table where each row represents an age, and there is a column for each race representing the count of mothers of that age. This approach may or may not be on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'age' and get the `mean` of logical `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
birthwt %>%
    group_by(age) %>%
     summarise(perc = mean(race == 1))
# A tibble: 24 x 2
#     age  perc
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1    14 0.333
# 2    15 0.333
# 3    16 0.286
# 4    17 0.25 
# 5    18 0.6  
# 6    19 0.625
# 7    20 0.333
# 8    21 0.417
# 9    22 0.769
#10    23 0.308
# … with 14 more rows
```

---

Or an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(birthwt)[,  .(perc = mean(race == 1)), age]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
birthwt$perc <- with(birthwt, ave(race == 1, age))
```

Or another base R option is

```
with(birthwt, tapply(race == 1, age, FUN = mean))
```

Or with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(perc = race == 1) ~ age, birthwt, FUN = mean)
```

Or with `by`

```
by(birthwt$race == 1, birthwt$age, FUN = mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can count the number of `race` which are white for each `age` and divide it by total number of rows for each age to get ratio.

```
library(dplyr)
birthwt %>%
  group_by(age) %>%
  summarise(perc = sum(race == 1)/n())

# A tibble: 24 x 2
#     age  perc
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1    14 0.333
# 2    15 0.333
# 3    16 0.286
# 4    17 0.25 
# 5    18 0.6  
# 6    19 0.625
# 7    20 0.333
# 8    21 0.417
# 9    22 0.769
#10    23 0.308
# … with 14 more rows
```

---

In base R, we can use `aggregate` following the same logic

```
aggregate(race~age, birthwt,function(x) sum(x == 1)/length(x))
```

Or something similar to your approach using `table`, we could do

```
tab <- table(birthwt$age, birthwt$race)
tab[, "1"]/rowSums(tab)
```